# Protect Sheet, Unlock "Allow Edit Ranges"

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large workbook and protecting sheets and unlocking the allowable ranges is time consuming so I was attempting to throw a module together to automate it. However, I'm sure you can see that it doesn't work. If I unlock the ranges and protect the sheet, then the ranges are just relocked, and if I protect the sheet and unlock the ranges--well it hits me with a Method 'Range' of object'_Worksheet' failed on the .Locked lines. Any assistance would be much appreciated, code below:

```
Sub ProtectSheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sheetPassword As String
Dim range1Password As String
Dim range2Password As String

sheetPassword = Worksheets("Data Validation").Range("XFD1048576").Value
range1Password = Worksheets("Data Validation").Range("XFD1048575").Value
range2Password = Worksheets("Data Validation").Range("XFD1048574").Value

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Tab.Color = RGB(33, 28, 91) Then
        If Not ws.ProtectContents Then
            ws.Protect sheetPassword
        End If

        ws.Range("RestInputs").Locked = False
        ws.Range("CAInputs").Locked = False

    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: You can only lock/unlock ranges when the worksheet is unprotected, so do that before protecting the sheet. "If I unlock the ranges and protect the sheet, then the ranges are just relocked" - protecting a sheet doesn't affect a range's `Locked` property

Comment: @TimWilliams I tried it out that way, but when I would go to the sheets, they would be protected but the "Allow Edit Ranges" were still prompting me for their password. Note, the ranges I am talking about are not named ranges, they are AllowEditRanges

Comment: All sheets has ranges with names "RestInputs" and "CAInputs" ?

Comment: Answered my own question below @ΑΓΡΙΑΠΕΣΤΡΟΦΑ I was using range instead of AllowEditRange

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ProtectSheets()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sheetPassword As String
Dim range1Password As String
Dim range2Password As String
Dim allowEditRange1 As AllowEditRange
Dim allowEditRange2 As AllowEditRange

sheetPassword = Worksheets("Data Validation").Range("XFD1048576").Value
range1Password = Worksheets("Data Validation").Range("XFD1048575").Value
range2Password = Worksheets("Data Validation").Range("XFD1048574").Value

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Tab.Color = RGB(33, 28, 91) Then
        If Not ws.ProtectContents Then
            ws.Protect sheetPassword
        Else
            ws.Unprotect sheetPassword
        End If
        
        ws.Unprotect sheetPassword
        
        Set allowEditRange1 = ws.Protection.AllowEditRanges("RestInputs")
        allowEditRange1.ChangePassword range1Password
        
        Set allowEditRange2 = ws.Protection.AllowEditRanges("CAInputs")
        allowEditRange2.ChangePassword range2Password
        
        ws.Protect sheetPassword
        allowEditRange1.Unprotect range1Password
        allowEditRange2.Unprotect range2Password
    End If
Next ws
```

End Sub

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).